# Remove Duplicates not working on Date values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using VBA code to remove duplicates on a sheet where I have copied data from two sources. Prior to copying the data, I am using other VBA code to format the data so that the formats are identical to the respective data by column. However, the problem is that when I run the remove duplicates code, it is not removing the duplicates. I have done testing by running the process manually (Data->Remove Duplicates). I have tested this one column at a time and discovered that the culprit is the column(s) with the date/time in them. So, to make sure that the data was the same, I am using the serial date/time numbers in the cells, and still have the same issue. Please see the pictures below of the steps I took in the manual process (which are the same results if I run this with my code).

[image: This is the data before the RD process]
This is the data before the RD process

[image]
This shows my selections

[image]
And this is the result. I cannot figure out why the last row was not removed as a duplicate of the first row when they are clearly identical. Can anyone help figure this out?

Comment: This has to do with the fact that a date/time is a rounded number format.  There are probably extra numbers way way down the decimal.  You can try creating another column that changes the dates to text using `=Text(G2,"mm/dd/yyyy")` then use that column to delete.

Comment: @scottcraner I did extend it out to the maximum of 30 decimal places with the same result. I have also formatted the date column with different variations, all ended with this result. I will try your text idea in a few minutes.

Comment: @ScottCraner So your suggestion almost works. I did this with just the date part as you wrote it and also ran it with the time added in `=Text(G2,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) (Capturing the time for this project is critical as we are trying to validate the two sets of data, someone may input an incorrect time, and we need to capture that). After further review, some of the serials date numbers do show a difference that would be attributed to rounding, but not all of the data shows this. Example, I have a set that did not remove the duplicate and both have the serial time as: 42430.334027777800000.

Comment: How do you round up the date/time serial to change this: 42430.616666666700000 and this: 42430.616666666600000
to show as this: 03/01/2016 14:48 so that when you run remove duplicates (either manually or with VBA code), one of these entries gets removed?

Comment: if you only care about the minute then try this `=INT(G2) + TIME(Hour(G2),MINUTE(G2),0)` and see if that rounds it sufficiently to make them the same.

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately that did not work either. There is still data that will not get deleted. But this may be a deeper problem. The examples I provided in my comment above show tw times that have .#####667 and .#####666. This part I get why it was not removed. But there are also rows that have 42430.125000000000000
 in both rows and the duplicate is not removed. Same result with what I tried, both with code and manually, and also with both of your suggestions. I will say that your last suggestion did round the numbers up, but the duplicate remained anyway.

Comment: Well crud, I am out of ideas.  I hope someone smarter than I can help you with your dilemma.  Sorry.

Comment: @ScottCraner No worries. I appreciate all of your suggestions. They all seemed valid. I just can't understand how this is removing some of the duplicates, but not all of them. The formats are the same when attempting to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to check the source of your data when you are pulling from multiple sources. The second hand data I received was imported and saved as Excel 97-2003 .xls. Then the user did a Save As Excel Workbook (.xlsx). Even when you do a save as from .xls to .xlsx, it will keep the formatting of the .xls workbook. I had them run the export again but directly into a .xlsx format. This corrected the issue outlined in the question. It does not matter how much formatting you do (at least everything I tried), it will never match.

The moral of this story is to verify the initial format version of the data you are receiving.